# Using HttpResponseMessage, how to load cache data when the user does not have internet?

Tags: c#, windows-8, httpresponse, .net-4.5

I'm programming a software using .NET FRAMEWORK 4.5 in METRO APPLICATIONS. I'm using the classes HttpClient and HttpResponseMessage to get the feeds from a RSS.

```
    private async Task<IList<FeedDataItem>> CreateRecipesAndRecipeGroups(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        try
        {
            response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // here I need to load the last feeds loaded
        }
    }
```

As you can see in my code, for example if I don't have internet, the program should load the previous or latest feeds.

Does you have idea about how can I fix this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

serialize the last downloaded feed to disk, when no internet available load from disk [Quickstart: Reading and writing a file (Metro style apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx)